# ¿Ciclo Loop en ensamblador, de 0 a 9?

Tags: ensamblador, programación-bajo-nivel

Tengo que hacer un ciclo en lenguaje ensamblador de 1 a 10 que muestre los números, ya el ciclo lo tengo pero no sé como hacer la interrupción para que muestre los números en pantalla, el ciclo es el siguiente:

**Assembly**

```
.model small
.stack
.data
.code
    PAGE 60,132
    TITLE EJLOOP (EXE) ilustración de LOOP
    ; ----------------------------------------…
    ORG 100H
    BEGIN PROC NEAR
        MOV AX,01 ; iniciación de AX
        MOV BX,01 ; BX y
        MOV DX,01 ; DX a 01
        MOV CX,10 ; iniciar
        A20: ; número de iteraciones
        LOOP A20 ; decrementar CX
        ; iterar si es diferente de 0
        MOV AX, 4C00H ; salida a DOS
        INT 21H
    BEGIN ENDP ; fin de procedimiento
.exit
end
```

Pero ¿cómo hago la interrupción para mostrar los números??

Answer (score 2):

En assembler hay muchas formas de hacer `loops` como el que deseas, lo más básico podría ser un [jump](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html) combinado con el uso de [etiquetas](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-5477/esqaq/index.html).

Por ejemplo:

```
MOV CL, 10
ETIQUETA1:
<LO-QUE-QUIERAS-HACER-DENTRO-DEL-LOOP>
DEC CL
JNZ ETIQUETA1
```

([JNZ](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html) significa `Jump if not zero`)

Pero también puedes usar la sentencia `loop`, algo como:

```
LOOP ETIQUETA1
```

Y `ETIQUETA1` contendrá el código que quieras ejecutar dentro del loop. Acá no hay un contador porque la sentencia `loop` asume que dicho contador es el registro `ECX`, de modo que un ejemplo más completo podría ser así:

```
mov ECX,10
ETIQUETA1:
<LO-QUE-QUIERAS-HACER-DENTRO-DEL-LOOP>
loop ETIQUETA1
```

Un ejemplo funcional que imprime los números del 1 al 9 iría así:

```
section .text
   global _start        ;must be declared for using gcc

_start:                 ;tell linker entry point
   mov ecx,10
   mov eax, '1'

l1:
   mov [num], eax
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   push ecx

   mov ecx, num        
   mov edx, 1        
   int 0x80

   mov eax, [num]
   sub eax, '0'
   inc eax
   add eax, '0'
   pop ecx
   loop l1

   mov eax,1             ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int 0x80              ;call kernel
section .bss
num resb 1
```

Puedes buscar más sobre [mov](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_addressing_modes.htm) y las [interrupciones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_(x86_instruction)) (o instrucciones).

Espero te sirva.